# How to disable some DataGrid cells

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using a DataGrid to display some data in my WPF-application.

How can I disable cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the column level, set IsReadOnly Property.

at the cell level, you need DataGridTemplateColumn With TextBox on DataTemplate.

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <!--Column level - all column its "read only"-->
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding AAA}"  IsReadOnly="True" />

    <!--Cell level - Cell its "read only" Depending data bindings -->
    <DataGridTemplateColumn >
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding BBB.CCC}" IsReadOnly="{Binding BBB.AllowEdit}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: i didn't understand what did you mean with BBB.AllowEdit sorry because i m just a begginer

Comment: This is just an example.
If you want Cell will be editable based on information in the row itself (source line - DataContext), so I imagined a situation that you property row called BBB and it also contains a string (CCC) and a field of Boolean named "AllowEdit", used to determine if the cell will editable.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of acheiving this, but you can maybe setup the RowLoaded event and in this event you should get a Collection of cells. Here you can set it to ReadOnly and maybe also disabled. I am not 100% sure about this in WPF, but it Works fine i Silverlight.